# How to hide visited links after a click to button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

There are a list of links on a page and some of them are already visited by me. I have to make them invisible after any action(checking a checkbox, clicking button, etc).

I tried to use jQuery: `$("a:visited").hide(300);` but it doesn't seem to work.

**UPD**: So, the scenario is:

1) the user clicks a button;

2) all the visited links disappear.

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/samosfator/EaAPY/1/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use jQuery to Select Visited Links](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1210871/use-jquery-to-select-visited-links)

Comment: Not possible: https://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/03/privacy-related-changes-coming-to-css-vistited/

Comment: @andi, But what about such a hack: after a click to any link on a page it is pushed to an array which is stored using WebStorage. And when user clicks to button, script hide all links from the array. Is it possible to do such a way?

Comment: You mean only hide the links that the user clicked while he was on that page?  That should be ok.  If you're not trying to manipulate visited links which the user visited before he came to your page, then you won't bump into that security issue.  Another possibility, depending on your needs: you are allowed to change the color of visited links, so maybe you could "hide" them by setting them to the same color as the background.

Answer (score 3):

You can try full `CSS` method :

```
a:visited { display: none; }
```

Or

```
a:visited { visibility: hidden; }
```

Or you can use a plugin method : [Visited Plugin by Remy Sharp](http://remysharp.com/2008/02/25/visited-plugin/)

Usage in `jQuery` :

```
$('a').visited().addClass('visited');
```

With `CSS` :

```
.visited { display: none; }
```

Or

```
.visited { visibility: hidden; }
```

Answer (score 3):

ok, so try this

in your css file

```
.foo a:visited{
    display:none;
}
```

in your javascript

```
$('button').on('click', function(e){
    $('ul').addClass('foo');
})
```

Comment: ah ok sorry, can you give a bit of html please

Comment: @jeremycastelli, here is [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/samosfator/EaAPY/1/)

Comment: I just discover that it's not possible to do what we want with a :visited link as you can read in this page

https://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/03/privacy-related-changes-coming-to-css-vistited/